# Namespace in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, namespaces, xamarin.android, system

I have xamarin application and want to use:

```
using System.Media;
```

but it writes me: SeverityThe type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
What can I do? Thanks

Comment: Xamarin uses a subset of the .net Framework. Said that, that namespace is missing, and for a good reason, on each platform the audio API is very different, so check the API for each one or use some sort of plugin (like here is explained: https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-with-the-media-plugin-for-xamarin/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use it on a PCL project most likely its because those libraries are not available. Portable Class Libraries only offer a subset of the full .NET functionality. You can probably try installing a related NuGet Package like the one Gusman suggested and use its functions to achieve your aim instead.